# Clustered Barplots: Problems with labels

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a dataset that looks like that, I want to plot the exact same bar plot in R.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OSqo.png]

This is what I've been trying:

```
barplot(as.matrix(table[,2:8]), beside = T, ylim= c(0,1),
        col = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", 
                "orange", "purple", "cyan", "grey", 
                "deeppink", "red4", "black", "brown"))
```

I get a bar plot, but now when I want to change the labels instead of a,b,c...g to this:

```
(-0.20,-0.15) 
(-0.15,-0.10)
.
.
.
(0.20,0.25)
```

I get an X character in front of every label I was trying to write:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkUXI.png]

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! It is much easier to help you if you provide a small sample of your data. [**See here on how to easily create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Thanks.

Comment: Show the whole function that you used to change the labels. It's likely the source of the problem.

Comment: It sounds as though you might have tried to change then ames of the dataframe named 'table'.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I didn't know how to change them in R, so I opened my data in a textedit and change the names of the variables there, but i got that strange result

Comment: I suppose `table` is your data table. If you type `str(table)` at the command line and then post the output as an edit to your question, you are much more likely to get help.

Comment: A great resource when you want a graph that "looks like this other graph" is the [chart chooser](http://www.yaksis.com/posts/r-chart-chooser.html).  Yours is the "column chart".  Click on the name and it will give you example code.

Comment: Note that @nacnudus URL will give you example using `ggplot2` - as I commented in your other post this package is much more powerful than R's standard plot function.